# The hierarchy of single pages with custom post types in WordPress

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-post-type

I have a custom post type named **cities**.
For this custom post type I will have N cities related.

I'm trying to create the files for theses pages and I thought this would work:

**single.php** - the generic one

**single-cities.php** - To list the cities

**single-cities-{city-slug}.php** - To bring the information for THE city

**When I try:**

**/cities** - It's showing the single.php content, not the single-cities content with the list.

**/cities/sao-paulo** - It's working. It shows the information about Sao Paulo.

**Test:**

If I delete the **single-cities-{city-slug}.php**, and try to access **/cities/sao-paulo**, it will bring the **single-cities.php**

What am I doing wrong in this hierarchy?

My code to register the custom post type:

```
$city_args = array(
  'labels'              => $labels,
  'public'              => true,
  'has_archive'         => true,
  'publicly_queryable'  => true,
  'query_var'           => true,
  'capability_type'     => 'post',
  'hierarchical'        => false,
  'supports'             => array(
    'title'
  ),
  'exclude_from_search' => false,
  'menu_icon'           => 'dashicons-building'
);

register_post_type('cities', $city_args);
```

Thanks!

---

**UPDATE**

I think I misunderstood the concept of a single page.
The single.php is just to render a single post, not to list the posts for a custom post type.

Reading more about this hierarchy, I'm trying to understand how my structure of listing cities and then bring the city information would fit.

Maybe I should create a page for cities, and then inside this page (page-cities.php), create the code to bring all the cities.

Clicking on each city, it should go to the single.php, is that it??

Comment: add this code to other theme and try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll want archive-cities.php to list all cities, single-cities for one post. Use this as a reference: https://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Type_Templates

Answer (score 1):

The page listing all your posts is called an Archive, which lives at the slug declared in the register_post_type arguments.

/cities - This is your archive page, so it will call **archive-cities.php**

/cities/sao-paulo - This is a single post. It will first look for **single-cities-{city-slug}.php**, then for **single-cities.php**.

In most cases, you would only use **single-cities-{city-slug}.php** to make a unique template file for a specific city. Assuming every city post uses an identical layout, you only need **single-cities.php**.